# Why am I getting three dots in Auto Layout?

Tags: xcode, autolayout

I tried doing auto layout but I keep on getting three dots. How do I fix this?

Screen shot of how it looks below.

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xougil1xtwl4we6/Screenshot%202015-06-18%2023.20.40.png?dl=0]

Comment: because label content is longer than label's width

Comment: How come on the left side the whole content shows but on the left only part of it does?

Comment: you pinned the left and right edges...so...it happens...and because you use truncate tail...it makes a dots at the right side

Comment: no this is iphone layout and how would I fix it if i wanted to keep the same font size?

Comment: ok...just pinned both edges to 0

Comment: I pinned both sides to 0 but this is how it turned out https://www.dropbox.com/s/qu4lklt4i2ew9vk/Screenshot%202015-06-18%2023.36.54.png?dl=0

Comment: Is there any reason why score and 0 are so spaced out on the right but not on the left?  https://www.dropbox.com/s/4brunhmc0gb3sp2/Screenshot%202015-06-19%2000.03.12.png?dl=0     http://puu.sh/iurnp/e965e25765.png

Comment: same issue....you pinned the left edges of score

Comment: I created UIImages, buttons, etc through code, not storyboard. Is there anyway to do AutoLayout through code. https://www.dropbox.com/s/d2vt6b9kytew94k/Screenshot%202015-06-19%2000.13.21.png?dl=0

Comment: yes... just google it autolayout with code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pinned both edges to `0` to get max width for label regarding screen sizes...and still content is too long then it displays 3 dots as per option truncate tail...For that you have to make a font size bit smaller or make multiline label...

[image]